# setup.py sdist/install substitutes 'plus' symbol in version

Tags: python, distutils

I have a project with the following versioning, which complies with [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/):

```
0.4.40+e39e255
```

I exploit ['local' version](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#id73) to store latest commit hash. When I do `python setup.py sdist`, a package `project_title-0.4.40-e39e255.tar.gz` is created, which when later deployed and installed with `pip` persists `project_title-0.4.40-e39e255` version, which is not PEP 440 compatible. Same with `python setup.py install` command:

```
...
Finished processing dependencies for price-watch==0.4.40-e39e255
```

How do I create a package with 'plus' in the version? Is something wrong with my environment?

**UPD**
The project is open source, so I'll add links to the real code:

- [fabfile.py](https://github.com/yentsun/price_watch/blob/5a83781cd016d81c5f03e5f9d27f72305448c13f/fabfile.py#L280) where I prepare the package
- [setup.py](https://github.com/yentsun/price_watch/blob/5a83781cd016d81c5f03e5f9d27f72305448c13f/setup.py)

**UPD2**
`VERSION.txt`, which is mentioned in the code but not present in the repo, is the output of `git describe --tags` and contains something like:

```
0.4-39-g5f530aa
```

**UPD3** `VERSION` in `setup.py` is actually what I need:

```
In[7]: with open('VERSION.txt') as f:
...        VERSION = f.read().strip().replace('-g', '+').replace('-', '.')
...     
In[8]: VERSION
Out[8]: '0.4.42+b4b4e13'
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, using a very simple `setup.py` (basically a variant of the first setup.py example in the distutils documentation). Can you create a minimal example that shows this behaviour?

Comment: I've added some links to the code

Comment: What does the `VERSION.txt` file look like? Since it's not included in the repository, thus running `setup.py sdist` fails.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still can't reproduce the problem. I get a file like `price_watch-0.4.39+5f530aa.tar.gz`, using either Python 2.7.9 or Python 3.4.3. Perhaps it's some weird internationalization problem, but I honestly wouldn't know about that.

Comment: Btw, have you checked that the line `VERSION = f.read().strip().replace('-g', '+').replace('-', '.')` does the right thing for you (e.g., simply on the Python prompt)? So that's indeed a (likely) distutils problem, and not something with the string replacement.

Comment: I've just noticed that even `python setup.py install` outputs: `Finished processing dependencies for price-watch==0.4.40-e39e255`